# Wires Coming Out Of Center Console

Tags: electrical

I bought a 2011 Ram 1500 about 6 months ago. I removed the rubber liner for a small compartment in my center console. When I tried putting it back I realized it would not go down all the way and found a small piece with 2 wires connected to it coming through between the plastic. I am wondering what this is.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an LED light most likely aftermarket from an old security system.

Comment: Great, thanks. Should I just shove it back under the plastic then? Or cut it off, or something else?

Comment: @l3v You could see where it goes, they may not have taken the alarm system out. Nothing wrong with just putting it back where it was either.

Comment: I think it's an indicator light for the lock on the secret compartment. Or the "armed" light for the passenger ejector seat.